# Create Column with MAX

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a problem and I have a feeling that a simple SQL query can solve it.
I have a table containing the data from the example below and I need "Output" column.

PID column has duplicates and I don't want to disturb that column.

What I need is to calculate P_Second based on PID.

- If P_Seconds value is unique for one PID, I need only one entry in the 'Output' column.
- If it is not unique then I need Max Seconds in the 'Output' column.
- If PID is `Null`, I need it to be only `Null`.

[image]

Comment: Your output doesn't conform to your rules.  It seems like all -- or almost all -- of the output column should have values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the output column populated once per `p_id` and where `p_seconds` first hits its maximum value.  "First" is determined by the `pry` column.

That is a window function with conditional logic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by p_id order by p_seconds desc, pry asc) = 1
             then p_seconds
        end) as output
from t;
```

Comment: Got what I want. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT PID, MAX(P_SECONDS) OUTPUT
from table
GROUP BY PID
```

If they are all the same, the MAX is also the same. If they are different, the MAX is choosen.